# Finding variable names for a function from a dictionary list

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary that I would like to reference all of the values with a list inside the dictionary

```
import pandas as pd
 
data= [["john","","","","","","","","","","","",""]]
df= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['firstName', 'lastName', 'state', 'Communication_Language__c', 'country', 'company', 'email', 'industry', 'System_Type__c', 'AccountType', 'customerSegment', 'Existing_Customer__c', 'GDPR_Email_Permission__c'])
filename= 'Template'
 
parsing={
"firstName": ["req_cols","capitalize"],
"lastName": ["req_cols", "capitalize"],
"state":["valid", "states","capitalize"],
"Communication_Language__c": "lang",
"country": ["req_cols","valid","capitalize"],
"company":"req_cols",
"email":"req_cols",
"industry":["valid","capitalize"],
"SME_Vertical__c":"valid",
"System_Type__c":["valid","capitalize"],
"AccountType":["valid","capitalize"],
"customerSegment":"capitalize",
"Existing_Customer__c":"req_cols",
"GDPR_Email_Permission__c":"req_cols"
}
```

I want to create a function that references all the dictionary keys that have a value in the list "capitalize" and then it takes those keys matches it to the columns in the df and then capitalizes all the content in the values under those columns.

desired output: the code finds that firstName has Capitalize in the dictionary list, it finds the column called firstName and capitalizes the value so "john" become "John"

I have thought something like this might accomplish the task but it does not.

```
def capitalize(parsing.keys(capitalize), df):
    df[capitalize] = str.title(df[capitalize])
return df
```

How do I make a function that reads the keys of a dictionary and the values in the dictionary list and then does str.title() on the column values of the df?

Answer (score 1):

Using [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function

**Code**

```
df2 = df.apply(lambda column: column.str.capitalize() if "capitalize" in parsing[column.name] else column)
```

**Explanation**

Used apply to process each column of Dataframe (e.g. axis = 0 by default)

- "capitalize" in parsing[column.name] True when either

  - parsing[column.name] equals string "capatalize" or
  - "capitalize" in list of strings of parsing[column.name]

**Test**

```
data= [["john","henry","california","english","usa","google","google.com","technology","unknown","large","ads","yes","unknown"],
       ["bob","johnson","florida","english","usa","tesla","tesla.com","technology","unknown","large","cars","no","unknown"]]
df= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['firstName', 'lastName', 'state', 'Communication_Language__c', 'country', 'company', 'email', 'industry', 'System_Type__c', 'AccountType', 'customerSegment', 'Existing_Customer__c', 'GDPR_Email_Permission__c'])

df2 = df.apply(lambda column: column.str.capitalize() if "capitalize" in parsing[column.name] else column)
display(df2)
```

*Output*

```
    firstName   lastName    state   Communication_Language__c   country company email   industry    System_Type__c  AccountType customerSegment Existing_Customer__c    GDPR_Email_Permission__c
0   John    Henry   California  english Usa google  google.com  Technology  Unknown Large   Ads yes unknown
1   Bob Johnson Florida english Usa tesla   tesla.com   Technology  Unknown Large   Cars    no  unknow
```